# How can I mass change several url's using .htaccess (redirect 301 and rewriterule)?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I mass change several url's using .htaccess (redirect 301 and rewriterule)?

From:

www.domain.com/imo-brasil/imoveis/rural--fazendas/fazenda-monte-alegre/514/

www.domain.com/imo-brasil/imoveis/rural--fazendas/

to:

www.domain.com/imo-brasil/imoveis/fazendas/fazenda-monte-alegre/514/

www.domain.com/imo-brasil/imoveis/fazendas/

I've made some attempts with no success. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should be enough for handling them:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(imo-brasil/imoveis)/rural-(.+)$ $1/$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Try it again, sorry it was a typo.

Comment: The internal server error remains. I'm using joomla and those folders are not fisical directories. Dont know if it matters.

Comment: One more edit, Try it again as **the first rule** in your .htaccess

Comment: No error this time but it redirects to www.domain.com/imo-brasil/